# Unable to run Django on Mac OS X

Tags: mac-osx, python, django

I'm working with a [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) project on my Mac (running [Leopard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Leopard)) and I want to show it to my team. I've already passed the neccessary port forwards from my router to my Mac's LAN IP address but it doesn't work.

I've also tried running the [XAMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) server since that always worked with my Windows XP computer but it still doesn't work. Whenever I type my `>` it's showing a Page Load Error. Is this possibly an issue with an Mac OS X configuration that I need to setup first to allow my port forwards to get in? It's my first time to do this with Mac, perhaps I need to configure something else in network preferences?

Comment: anything in the error logs?

Comment: Are you saying it works on your computer, but no one else can access it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your using the built-in "manage.py runserver" command?  Since this is only intended for development it binds to localhost.  You need to use "manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" to bind to all addresses.

Note: This webserver is really *not* intended for production, please don't use as a way to host your live site.

Comment: +1 on not using in production. However, sometimes during rapid development-phases, it is helpful to be able to expose the local dev environment when Django is used as an API.